# Google Form to Telegram

Tags: google-sheets, telegram-bot, google-forms

i'm new to coding, may i ask if there's anyone know how to code, when the value in google form (Spreadsheet) is equal or less than 2.5 it will send warning text to the telegram. Thank you, appreciate your kindness

Answer (score -1):

Create an [on form submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) trigger and do [sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) with [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl)

Comment: How to do that ? Sorry i’m so new, is there anything i can refer to ?

Comment: References added